# Как программно установить элементу высоту, равную высоте экрана (той части, которая отводится под приложение)?

Tags: android

На текущий момент делаю таким способом:
Код `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorGray"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/test"
                android:background="@color/Missed"
                android:gravity="bottom">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="text"
                    android:textSize="40dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Код `onCreate` в `MainActivity`:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels;

View v = findViewById(R.id.test);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams par = v.getLayoutParams();
par.height = height;
v.setLayoutParams(par);
```

Проблема в том, что высота элемента оказывается больше, чем надо - `ScrollView` добавил специально для того, что бы показать прокрутку
[image: Скрин приложения]

как видно на картинке - `TextView` полностью не входит в экран. К слову, лишняя прокрутка на глазок равна высоте панели уведомлений телефона. Так как ее (прокрутку) можно убрать?

Comment: В общем, действительно, если отнять высоту "шторки", то все получается нормально, но все же - это единственное решение?

Comment: Считайте не высоту экрана, а высоту вашего корневого `LinearLayout`, который `match_parent`.

Comment: @eugeneek, начиная с какого момента модно считывать высоту? В `onResume` она равна -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить нужную вам высоту, берите не размер всего экрана, а размер корневой вью, у которой установлены значения для высоты `match_parent`.

Но в методах `onCreate` и, даже в `onResume` активити, вью ещё не знают свой размер и вы можете получить 0. Самый простой способ получить высоту после измерения, это поставить такой запрос в очередь лейаута с помощью метода `post`. И далее уже устанавливайте полученную высоту нужной вью:

```
final View rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);
final View v = findViewById(R.id.test);

rootView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int height = rootView.getHeight(); //height is measured
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams par = v.getLayoutParams();
        par.height = height;
        v.setLayoutParams(par);
    }
});
```

Код из `Runnable` будет выполнен уже после всех измерений вью и вы будете иметь актуальное значение высоты.